# Difference between angular promise objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference between promise 1 and promise 2? The 1st one has only $$state property, the second one has additionally error and success callback. Why are they different?

```
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

  </div>
 </div>




angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
//promise 1    
console.log('p1',$http.get("/echo/json/").then(
  function(){ console.log('s1',arguments); }, 
  function(){ console.log('e1',arguments); }
 )
);

var p = $http.get("/echo/json/");
//promise 2
console.log('p2',p);
p.then(
  function(){ console.log('s2',arguments);}, 
  function(){console.log('e2',arguments);});
}
);
```

console log says:

```
p1 Promise { $$state: Object }
   $$state: Object
   __proto__: Object
 p2 Promise { $$state: Object } 
      $$state: Object
      error: (fn) 
      success: (fn)
      __proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you provide the console.log output?

Comment: @BenBracha in second Promise object there are 2 additional callbacks

Answer (score 0):

In your first case, you call $http.get("/echo/json/") that returns a Promise. After that you apply "then" method with callbacks to this promise (that returns you new promise), and after that your console output is executed (and you have this new promise there). Callback functions are executed when real result comes back.
In the second case, you create promise, logs it (as a first created promise, nothing more, no callbacks), and after that you apply "then" method with callbacks to your promise. Again, callback functions will be executed after results are received. 
You can find description in [Promise API documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: Why the first "new promise" created by "then" does not have succcess and error callbacks and the 2nd one has? It's by design or there are other differences? I was wondering because I thought that this 2 promises should have same interface or I do not understand it well?

Comment: What version of Angular do you use? In earlier versions (1.3 for reference), $http.get returned "a promise with two $http specific methods: success and error." (see official docs for details: http://devdocs.io/angularjs~1.3/api/ng/service/%24http ). You see exactly these methods in your console. They are deprecated in older versions, take a look at this discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10508